# How to add bind mount in redhat kickstart?

Tags: linux, redhat, kickstart

I would like to add a bind mount to my redhat server that gets reimaged via kickstart. Problem I am facing is, it looks like %pre is too early and %post is too late. For example I would like to take out /var and put it in a different real mount like /bigfs/var. I would like to do it before any writes to /var. Theoretically I can do it in post where I could tar current /var, create bind mounts, untar. This seems a clunky way of doing it, wonder if there is a better way to insert entries in /etc/fstab when new filesystems get mounted and get added to /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 1):

Use %post --nochroot to avoid chrooting into the installed system, then edit /mnt/sysimage/etc/fstab in that block.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to manipulate `/etc/fstab` before the install is though the `part` command and that doesn't support bind mounts. I do the manipulation in the `%post` section as you describe.